# Postfix permit_sasl_authenticated before content_filter

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot, spamassassin

I have a postfix + dovecot + spamassassin setup which works great, but I would like to bypass all outgoing messages (sasl authenticated) from spam filtering. I must do something wrong, because I already implemented `permit_sasl_authenticated` in my `main.cf` but looks like it does not work.

My main.cf relevant part:

```
# SASL Auth for SMTP relaying
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = ...
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

# transports
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
local_recipient_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

# restrictions
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    defer_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient
    reject_unauth_destination
    reject_unauth_pipelining
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject_unverified_recipient
    reject_invalid_hostname
```

My master.cf relevant part:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no

spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=mail:mail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u ${recipient} -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

If I try to insert everything what is in `main.cf` to `master.cf` with `-o` option, it also does not help. What could be the solution to achive this? No other milters are used, only DKIM. So no amavis, clamav or something.

Comment: https://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#remote_only

Comment: It is not good at all, only if I connect with SASL from fixed IP address. Otherwise, I need to change everytime.

Answer (score 1):

SASL authenticated users should be using the `smtps` defined in `master.cf` for submission. You can remove the content filter for SMTPS from there by removing the line `-o content_filter=spamassassin` in that section.

Comment: And what if an SMTP server connects to SSL because it can? Then the spamassassin filter will be bypassed for them also.

Comment: The smtps should only be allowed for SASL authenticated users. Other MTAs are using STARTTLS on port 25.